# After successfully deploying Next.js app on AWS Amplify, https://www.example.com/api/any-route showing below error in console

Tags: deployment, next.js, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify, serverless

The app is deployed successfully but the API routes (/pages/api) are not working as expected, showing below error in the console.

Build is successful and deployed on aws-amplify, I have added environment variables correctly, don't know why this is happening?

Does aws-amplify doesn't support serverless functions writer inside `/api` folder??

```json
{
"error": {
"message": "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80",
"name": "Error",
"stack": "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16)",
"config": {
"url": "undefined/campaigns",
"method": "get",
"headers": {
"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
"User-Agent": "axios/0.21.4"
},
"auth": {},
"transformRequest": [null],
"transformResponse": [null],
"timeout": 0,
"xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
"xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
"maxContentLength": -1,
"maxBodyLength": -1,
"transitional": {
"silentJSONParsing": true,
"forcedJSONParsing": true,
"clarifyTimeoutError": false
}
},
"code": "ECONNREFUSED"
}
}
```

Here is the code

```javascript
import axios from 'axios';
import Cors from 'cors';
import rateLimit from '../../../utils/rate-limit';
import initMiddleware from '../../../lib/init-middleware';

// Initialize the cors middleware
const cors = initMiddleware(
  Cors({
    methods: ['POST'],
    origin: ['https://www.example.com', /\.example\.com$/],
  })
);

const limiter = rateLimit({
  interval: 60 * 1000, // 60 seconds
  uniqueTokenPerInterval: 500, // Max 500 users per second
});

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  await cors(req, res);

  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    try {
      await limiter.check(res, 50, 'CACHE_TOKEN');

      const { data } = await axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/campaigns`, {
        auth: {
          username: process.env.MAIL_SERVER_USERNAME,
          password: process.env.MAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
        },
      });
      return res.status(200).json(data);
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(429).json({ error });
    }
  } else {
    try {
      await limiter.check(res, 10, 'CACHE_TOKEN'); // 10 requests per minute
      return res.status(200).json('not allowed');
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(429).json({ error: 'Rate limit exceeded' });
    }
  }
};

export default handler;
```

Comment: Can you share the code of the API route you're accessing and that's returning the error? Where does `undefined/campaigns` URL come from?

Comment: Hi @juliomalves I have edited the post, please have a look

Comment: Looks like your `BASE_URL` environment variable isn't properly set in AWS Amplify. As you can see from the error message it's returning undefined (see url `undefined/campaigns`), hence why the request is failing.

Comment: Yes, aws amplify has a quite nasty bug, I wasted many hours on this, finally worked after addressing this https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/1987#issuecomment-885217940

Comment: Glad you got it working. Feel free to add a the solution that worked for you as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that environment variables are not getting reflected, so did some googling; found this solution and it worked for me.
Add your desired environment variable in the Amplify Console-like normal (steps)
Update (or create) your next.config.js file with the environment variable you added in the Amplify Console. E.g if you created an environment variable named MY_ENV_VAR in the console in step 1) above, then you would add the following:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    MY_ENV_VAR: process.env.MY_ENV_VAR
  }
};
```

Now after your next build you will be able to reference your environment variable (process.env.MY_ENV_VAR) in your SSR lambdas!

Here is the link: [Github](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/1987#issuecomment-885217940)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem Amplify only supports NextJS 11 at the moment. If you go with the default settings it will use the latest NextJS 12 and /api routes wont work, they return a 503 with a cloudformation permission error.

Specify next 11.1.3 in your package.json

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/08/aws-amplify-hosting-support-next-js-version-11/

Answer (score 0):

I also faced that problem. Amplify does not support v12 of next. Simply downgrade your next.js version in package.json to v1.1.3 and your routes will work as normal.

Best regrets.
Artem Meshkov

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31293258)